# Restarting wrapper.exe by Tanuki software as a Windows Service using command line

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, autohotkey

Would anyone know how can I restart this service without manually triggering it thru services.msc? How can I put it in a script where this service be automatically restarted as a service? thanks in advance!

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Tanuki\bin\wrapper.exe" -s "c:\Program Files (x86)\Tanuki\conf\MTG.conf"
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
C:\Users\Ning>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Tanuki\bin\wrapper.exe" -s "c:\Program Files (x86)\Tanuki\conf\MTG.conf"
Attempting to start MTG as an NT service.

Calling StartServiceCtrlDispatcher...please wait.

StartServiceControlDispatcher failed!

The -s and --service commands should only be called by the Windows
ServiceManager to control the Wrapper as a service, and is not
designed to be run manually by the user.

For help, type
c:\Program Files (x86)\Tanuki\bin\wrapper -?}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (run the script as administrator):

Starting a service:

```
RunWait, %comspec% /c "net start service_name",, Hide
```

Stopping a service:

```
RunWait, %comspec% /c "net stop service_name",, Hide
```

Replace "service_name" with the service name you want restart. 
Make sure that you are using the correct service name,
shown in the properties for that service (not the Display name).

Comment: How can I put this whole thing in there?

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Tanuki\bin\wrapper.exe" -s "c:\Program Files (x86)\Tanuki\conf\MTG.conf"

I'm also using wrapper.exe which uses configuration  from MTG.conf

Comment: The above code is for Autohotkey scripts. Try copying the code in an AHK script and run it as administrator (using the context menu).

Comment: Thanks man, it really started the service but I wanted to see it with a "Running" status in the services.mcs or in Service Management Console as well. How would that be?

Comment: Try [this Autohotkey script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/20237-winserv-start-stop-or-query-a-windows-service-winapi/) .